# How to compare string in solidity

Tags: solidity

How to perform a comparison between strings in solidity.

```
function Compare()  public{
   if ("Ab" == "AB"){
     return (2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In solidity we encoding and hasing to compare the strings. However, this is not for good password comparasion.

```
if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(c))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(d))){ 
    "enter something"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do comparison like following statement ,

```
function compareString(string calldata s1,string calldata s2) view public returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(bytes(s1)) == keccak256(bytes(s2)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the length first to make it more gas efficient. And if the length match you can make the actual comparison.

```
function hashCompareWithLengthCheck(string a, string b) internal returns (bool) {
    if(bytes(a).length != bytes(b).length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return keccak256(a) == keccak256(b);
    }
}
```

You can read about how it will save gas [in this article](https://github.com/fravoll/solidity-patterns/blob/master/docs/string_equality_comparison.md)